# Use GCM to send notifications to multiple devices

Tags: php, google-cloud-messaging

I need to send a notification to multiple devices via server but it didn't work for me,it works fine for one.So i tried to make a loop after getting all the `gcm_regid` but it doesn't work.Here is my code :
Function on main page :

```
function sendPushNotificationToAll(){
 var data = $('#form').serialize();      
$.ajax({
 url: "send_message(all).php",
type: 'GET',
data: data,
 beforeSend: function() {
},
success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
 $('.txt_message').val("");
 },
error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
}
 });
return false;
}
```

and send_message(all).php :

```
include_once './config.php';
if (isset($_GET["message"])) {
$message = $_GET["message"];

mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("gcm");
$fetch=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gcm_users");
$ids_array=array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch))
{
    $ids_array[]=$row['gcm_regid'];
}
$url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
$fields = array(
'registration_ids' => $ids_array,
data' =>  $message,         
);
$headers = array(
'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
'Content-Type: application/json'
);

// Open connection
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );

// Execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ($result === FALSE) {
ie('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
}
// Close connection
curl_close($ch);

    echo $result;
}
```

When I click on send nothing happens.

**update**
Ok so answering my own question :
This code misses on line which is :

```
$message = array("price" => $message);
```

That's all!

Comment: send_message(all).php gives me a parse error on line 19. Is that the problem that you get? If not fix, your question.

Comment: you got that error because of the google key which is included on config.php that i included,try with your key if you have one

Comment: Your data tag is missing a ' at the start. is that just a copying error? I dont see any immediate issue with the code.

Comment: you mean <?php ? yeah i didn't copied it because it's obvious! yeah and i don't see issues too but it didn't work :/

Comment: The parse error does not come from a missing google key. The question "Is that the problem that you get?" that I asked in my previous comment is not a rethorical question. Answer that question, and take the actions I recommended in my previous comment. BTW: I did add `<?php` when I tried to test your code.

Comment: this same code but without the loop works for one mobile .what is the line you mentioned?